# Is it possible to use a delegate or to pass a function as argument in Vimscript?

Tags: vimscript, plugin-system

I am trying to create a small plugin to learn vimscript, my goal is to create some functions processing a selected text and replacing it with the result. The script contains the following items:

- **Two functions processing text:** they take a string as parameter an return the string which should be used to replace the original text. For now I have only two but there might by a lot more in a few time.
- **A function getting the selected text:** which simply yank the last selection and return it.
- **A wrapper function:** which call a processing function, get its result and replace the old selection with this result.

For now my wrapper function looks like this:

```
function! Wrapper()
    " Get the string to insert
    let @x = Type1ProcessString(GetSelectedText())

    " remove the old selection
    normal gvd

    " insert the new string
    normal "xp
endfunction
```

And I have to create a second wrapper replacing the line 3 with

```
let @x = Type2ProcessString(GetSelectedText())
```

I'd like to give to my wrapper function a parameter containing the Process function to execute and use a generic call in line 3. For now I have tried using `call` different ways like, for example, this:

```
let @x = call('a:functionToExecute', GetSelectedText())
```

but I haven't been really succesful and `:h call` hasn't been really helpful on the delegate topic.

**To sum it up here are my questions:**

- How can I make only one wrapper function for all the processing ones?
- Is there something which works as a delegate in vimscript?
- If delegates doesn't exist what would be a "good" way to do what I want?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To answer your question: the prototype of `call()` in the manual is `call({func}, {arglist} [, {dict}])`; the `{arglist}` argument needs to be literally a List object, not a list of arguments.  That is, you have to write it like this:

```
let @x = call(a:functionToExecute, [GetSelectedText()])
```

This assumes `a:functionToExecute` is either a Funcref (see `:help Funcref`), or the name of a function (i.e. a string, such as `'Type1ProcessString'`).

Now, that's a powerful feature that gives Vim a sort of LISP-like quality,  but you'd probably seldom use it as above.  If `a:functionToExecute` is a string, the name of a function, then you can do this:

```
function! Wrapper(functionToExecute)
    " ...
    let s:processing = function(a:functionToExecute)
    let @x = s:processing(GetSelectedText())
    " ...
endfunction
```

and you'd call the wrapper with the name of the function:

```
call Wrapper('Type1ProcessString')
```

If on the other hand `a:functionToExecute` is a Funcref, you can call it directly:

```
function! Wrapper(functionToExecute)
    " ...
    let @x = a:functionToExecute(GetSelectedText())
    " ...
endfunction
```

but you need to call the wrapper like this:

```
call Wrapper(function('Type1ProcessString'))
```

You can check for existence of functions with `exists('*name')`.  This makes possible the following little trick:

```
let s:width = function(exists('*strwidth') ? 'strwidth' : 'strlen')
```

i.e. a function that uses the built-in `strwidth()` if Vim is new enough to have it, and falls back to `strlen()` otherwise (I'm not arguing that such a fallback makes sense; I'm just saying it can be done). :)

With dictionary functions (see `:help Dictionary-function`) you can define something resembling classes:

```
let g:MyClass = {}

function! g:MyClass.New(...)
    let newObj = copy(self)

    if a:0 && type(a:1) == type({})
        let newObj._attributes = deepcopy(a:1)
    endif
    if exists('*MyClassProcess')
        let newObj._process = function('MyClassProcess')
    else
        let newObj._process = function('s:_process_default')
    endif

    return newObj
endfunction

function! g:MyClass.getFoo() dict
    return get(get(self, '_attributes', {}), 'foo')
endfunction

function! g:MyClass.setFoo(val) dict
    if !has_key(self, '_attributes')
        let self._attributes = {}
    endif
    let self._attributes['foo'] = a:val
endfunction

function! g:MyClass.process() dict
    call self._process()
endfunction

function! s:_process_default()
    echomsg 'nothing to see here, define MyClassProcess() to make me interesting'
endfunction
```

Then you'd instantiate objects like this:

```
let little_object = g:MyClass.New({'foo': 'bar'})
```

And call its methods:

```
call little_object.setFoo('baz')
echomsg little_object.getFoo()
call little_object.process()
```

You can also have class attributes and methods:

```
let g:MyClass.__meaning_of_life = 42

function g:MyClass.GetMeaningOfLife()
    return get(g:MyClass, '__meaning_of_life')
endfunction
```

(notice no need for `dict` here).

Subclassing is something like this:

```
let g:MySubclass = copy(g:MyClass)
call extend(g:MySubclass, subclass_attributes)
```

The subtle point here is the use of `copy()` instead of `deepcopy()`.  The reason for this is to be able to access the attributes of the parent class by reference.  This can be achieved, but it's highly fragile and getting it right is far from trivial.  Another potential problem is that this kind of subclass conflates `is-a` with `has-a`.  For this reasons class attributes are usually not really worth the pain.

Ok, this should be enough to give you some food for thought.

Back to your initial code snippet, there are two details with it that could be improved:

- You don't need `normal gvd` to remove the old selection, `normal "xp` will replace it even if you don't kill it first
- Use `call setreg('x', [lines], type)` instead of `let @x = [lines]`.  This explicitly sets the type of the register `x`.  Otherwise you're relying on `x` already having the correct type (i.e. characterwise, linewise, or blockwise).

Comment: When you create functions in a dictionary directly (i.e. a "numbered function"), you don't need the `dict` keyword. This applies to your "class methods". See `:h numbered-function`.

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg Technically it applies to both class and object methods (i.e. there's no need for `dict` for any of the `MyClass` functions).  But I find that confusing, so I tend to add `dict` explicitly.

Comment: I see. So you add `dict` for object methods, but not for class methods, in order to help clarify your intent?

Comment: @lcd047 Thanks a lot for this amazing answer! I'll have to work on it but that is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg There's a subtility here, the meaning of `self` is different for class methods and for object methods -- it's the class itself in the former case, and the instance of the current object in the latter.  For this reason I always refer to the class itself as `g:MyClass`, never using `self`, and I mostly see the `dict` as a reminder that it's ok to use `self` (that is, a function that has `dict` always acts on an object instance).  Than again, I don't use class methods much, and when I do that I also tend to omit `dict` everywhere.  Yeah, self-consistency is my middle name. ;)

Comment: @lcd047 (and @ others too): About the dictionnary used as an object, is it a common way to use vimscript? I haven't looked at a lot of vimscript code yet so I'm not really aware of what the good practices are, so is that generally a good idea to use vimscript as an object oriented language with this dictionnary trick or should I do that only in some particular cases? (I don't want to flood the comments but I'm not sure it is worth a dedicated question tho)

Comment: @statox It's a conceptual scheme, thus OOP in Vim has the same uses and caveats as real OOP in other languages.  It's useful is you're creating objects to model the solution to a problem; it can really get you in a mess if you're creating objects to model the problem rather than the solution.  When done properly it can be invaluable for making things extensible.  So yes, I'd say using OOP is good practice, provided that you take your time to think things properly.  For small, one-time plugins you can get away just fine without OOP.  Then again, you can probably also get away without VimL.

Comment: @lcd047: Ok that seems legit. I probably won't use it for what I'm doing now but I'll take a look at that soon. Thanks for your answers :-)

Comment: @statox From your description above, your problem is precisely one where I'd use OOP right from the beginning.  That's why I wrote all that blurb about classes. _shrug_

Comment: @lcd047: Oh I see, I'll take some time to re-think the whole thing then!

Comment: Nice answer. A little comment regarding OOP implementation in VimL. I've moved away from anonymous functions lately as they are impossible to recognize in exception stacktrace. On this topic, see this Q/A on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39862874/how-to-debug-error-while-processing-function-in-vim-and-nvim

Answer (score 1):

Build the command in a string and use `:exe` to run it.  See [`:help execute`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#:execute) for more details.

In this case, `execute` is used to make the call to the function and put the result in the register, the different elements of the command must be concatenated with the `.` operator as a regular string. The line 3 should then become:

```
execute "let @x = " . a:functionToExecute . "(GetSelectedText())"
```