# Is it possible to create a function with the same name for different filetypes (and different implementations)?

Tags: vimscript, filetype, functions

Is it possible to create several functions with the same name whose implementation depends on the file type?

For example, I could imagine a function named `CurrentFunctionName` that returns the name of the function in which the cursor of the current buffer is. Since the determination of a function name depends on the file type, I need to create multiple implementations for `CurrentFunctionName` (Perl, C++, JavaScript etc).

This function could then be called in another (global) function with only one implementation:

```
fu Log(text)
   call WriteToLog(CurrentFunctionName() . ': ' . a:text)
endfu
```

Which `CurrentFunctionName` is now called within `Log` is then dependent on the file type of the buffer that was active when `Log` was called.

Is there something like that?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a duplicate but I think that lcd047's answer to [this question of mine](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3920/1841) could help you.

Comment: Not sure if it will work, maybe try to implement each function in proper `ftplugin/<filetype>.vim`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside `ftplugin/<filetype>.vim` you could set a buffer local variable to point to the correct function:

```
function s:CurrentFunctionName() abort
  " Implement the function here
endfunction

let b:CurrentFunctionName = function('<SID>CurrentFunctionName')
```

In other scripts you can `call b:CurrentFunctionName()` and it will call the appropriate one based on what was set for the buffer in the ftplugin. This will fail if you try to call it when for a filetype which did not set this variable.

If you want a fallback you could define it like this (not in ftplugin):

```
function s:CurrentFunctionNameFallback() abort
  " Implement the fallback here
endfunction

autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *
    \ if !exists('b:CurrentFunctionName') |
    \   let b:CurrentFunctionName = function('<SID>CurrenFunctionNameFallback') |
    \ endif
```

Comment: Nice. However, I see a little caveat: the function cannot be loaded lazily. IIRC, a way to define funcrefs over autoloaded functions have been added to Vim lately. We could improve your solution with: `let b:CurrentFunctionName = function('namespace#filetype#funcname')`

Comment: Yes I think we can lazy load the funcref - that woudl be a good improvement. I kept the function immediate for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

You could just define the function in a `ftplugin` file. For example create the two files with content below them:

:~/.vim/ftplugin/a.vim:

```
function! Test()
    echom 'a'
endfunction
```

~/.vim/ftplugin/b.vim:

```
function! Test()
    echom 'b'
endfunction
```

Now make sure you have set `:filetype plugin on`. If you now open a `.a` file (or run `:setf a`) the `a.vim` file will be sourced and the function will be defined to echo `a`. If you open a `.b` file the other file will be sourced, the function will be redefined and a call to it will echo `b`, demonstrating that a function can do different things depending on the filetype.

It should be noted that if you open any other filetype, the function is not redefined and will therefore be dependent on the filetype that was last loaded. As you would probably not be calling the function for a filetype that does not define it, this would probably not be a problem. If it is you could `:delfunction` the function when the filetype changes to something else with an `autocmd`.

Comment: This won't work correctly. If I open `foo.cpp`, then `foo.vim`, then switch back to `foo.cpp`, the C++ function won't be reloaded. This is not enough to guarantee to always call the right specialisation.

Comment: @LucHermitte How to overcome this problem? This is exactly what I am facing right now.

Comment: @AnkitJain, we need a different, and more convoluted, workflow, see my answer for instance where I propose a way to have _filetype polymorphism_.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a mecanism for this in lh-dev (a library plugin dedicated to this kind of issues -- generic functions for generic plugins that can be specialized on filetype basis, which I abusively call "ft-polymorphism"). I use it in my generic refactoring plugin, and to automate the insertion of `import`/`#include` in mu-template snippets.

How does it works ?

- I usually have a generic front-end function, let's say `lh#dev#domain#verb()` when I follow something like the *NVI* pattern (from C++), but I may also not have this function and directly call the variation point from an unrelated function as I would do with the *template method* design pattern.
- I may have a default implementation (I don't remember the name I've chosen)
- and I have a few specialisations, for instance: `lh#dev#cpp#domain#verb()`, `lh#dev#vim#domain#verb()`, and so on.

Then I call the right function, from `lh#dev#domain#verb()`, thank to `lh#dev#options#call('domain#verb', &ft, param1, param2...)` that looks like this:

```
" Function: lh#dev#option#call(name, filetype, [, parameters])  {{{2
" @return lh#dev#{ft}#{name}({parameters}) if it exists, or
" lh#dev#{name}({parameters}) otherwise
" If {name} is a |List|, then the function name used is: {name}[0]#{ft}#{name}[1]
function! lh#dev#option#call(name, ft, ...) abort
  if type(a:name) == type([])
    let prefix = a:name[0]
    let name   = a:name[1]
  elseif type(a:name) == type('string')
    let prefix = 'lh#dev'
    let name   = a:name
  else
    throw "Unexpected type (".type(a:name).") for name parameter"
  endif

  let fts = lh#dev#option#inherited_filetypes(a:ft)
  call map(fts, 'v:val."#"')
  let fts += ['']
  for ft in fts
    let fname = prefix.'#'.ft.name
    if !exists('*'.fname)
      let file = substitute(fname, '#', '/', 'g')
      let file = substitute(file, '.*\zs/.*', '.vim', '')
      exe 'runtime autoload/'.file
    endif
    if exists('*'.fname) | break | endif
  endfor

  call s:Verbose('Calling: %1(%2)', fname, a:000)
  if s:verbose >= 2
    debug return call (function(fname), a:000)
  else
    return call (function(fname), a:000)
  endif
endfunction
```

The caveat? The `:for` loop is a nightmare when I'm debugging.

For more explanations on the topic, see it's related documentation: https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-dev#filetype-polymorphism . Notes: `lh#def#option#get()` has been moved to `lh#ft#option#get()` for dependency issues, it also supports my new project variables `p:foobar` (which act as shared `b:variables`).

Also note that if `namespace#cpp#domain#funcname()` doesn't exist, this function will try to execute `namespace#c#domain#funcname()`. A feature I've named *filetype inheritance* (I wasn't inspired ^^').